# what does [-4:] means in python?

Tags: python, nltk

I have learned in class that for Python, characters stars from [0]. For example in Monty Python, 'M'=0, 'o'=1, 'n'=2, 't'=3, 'y'=4, ' '=5, 'P'=6, 'y' = 7, 't' = 8, 'h'=9, 'o' = 10, and 'n' = 11.

But I am confused when I saw the following operation on NLTK:

```
genre_word = [(genre, word) for genre in ['news', 'romance']
                            for word in brown.words(categories=genre)]

genre_word[:4]
genre_word[-4:]
```

I thought all character numbering starts with `[0]`. What does the `[-4:]` means?

Comment: The some_list[-n] syntax gets the nth-to-last element. So some_list[-4] gets the last four elements.

Answer (score 1):

For any iterable in python `[-4:]` denotes the indexing of last four items of that iterable. For example :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list1[-4:]
```

> [3, 4, 5, 6]

```
str1 = 'Hello world'
str1[-4:]
```

> 'orld'

Answer (score 1):

It gets the last four elements of the sequence:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> l[-4:]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in python the indexing of an array starts with 0

let us say

```
my_word = 'hello world'
print(my_word[0])  #prints 'h'
```

in python we also have a feature to index from the last

let us say

```
my_word = 'hello world'
print(my_word[-1]) # prints 'd'
# - stands from last starting with index 1
print(my_word[-4:]) # prints 'orld'
# if you know the length you can directly use
print(my_word[7:])  # prints 'orld'
```

This feature helps you to print the values indexing from last if you don't know the length